# Built Android APK from Wakanda giving Parse Error when opening it

Tags: android, apk, wakanda

Trying to build an Android APK using Wakanda Digital App Factory 1.0.3

According to the Mobile Troubleshooter everything is Installed and listed as green.

At first i was getting lots of warnings like this:

> warning: java/lang/Double.class(java/lang:Double.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
>   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.

I found the warnings to be related to the JDK version i had installed. **I installed the latest from [oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and the warnings went away.**

---

Now without warnings, I see 1 error during the build:

> Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
>   [Environment] Error: Platform android already added.

However the APK is built and the build process ends with:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 7.664 secs
>   [Environment] Built the following apk(s):
>   /Users/tpenner/Documents/Wakanda/WakMon4D/WakMon4D/mobile/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk
>   [Build] Open the generated output for Android

I have enabled `Unsigned Sources` on my phone, but when i try to open the APK on my Samsung Galaxy S6 i get the following error:

> **Parse error**
>
> There was a problem parsing the package.

I have tried rebuilding the application and i keep getting the same parse error when attempting to install/open the APK.

I can successfully run the app in the Android Simulator using Wakanda's Run feature, but the built  cannot be parsed on my phone.

Note: *the parse error only happens with the **release** build* named <kbd>android-release-unsigned.apk</kbd>

Wakanda also built the following ***debug*** versions:
<kbd>android-debug-unaligned.apk</kbd>
<kbd>android-debug.apk</kbd>

***Both of the Debug versions work.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your release APK need to be signed.

Release built versions meant to be used for Google Play submission or production level usage. So when you try to install the unsigned copy your phone will get rejected since it's not signed, even if you checked `Allow install from unsigned Sources`.

Follow [this guide](http://www.androiddevelopment.org/2009/01/19/signing-an-android-application-for-real-life-mobile-device-usage-installation/), it just takes 5 minutes to sign an APK.